# In Economics, how likely is a R&R paper be finally accepted in a top field journal or top 5 journal?

Tags: data-request, academic-graduate, soft-question, research

Based on reliable data (if there is any), how likely is a R&R be **finally** accepted approximately?

---

Here is some numbers I found:

1. According to an [anonymous comment](https://www.econjobrumors.com/topic/conditionally-accepted-2?replies=10#post-6402965), the post RR acceptance rate for a "top journal" is about 25%.
2. According to an [anonymous "editor"](https://www.econjobrumors.com/topic/rr-acceptance-rates-by-journal), P(Acceptance|R&R and ranked below top 40 journal) is about 75%
3. One anonymous [comment](https://www.econjobrumors.com/topic/rr-acceptance-rates-by-journal) claims that the post RR acceptance rate of JFE is 85%, possibly based on the EJMR self-reported statistics on journal submissions.
4. A few [comments](https://www.econjobrumors.com/topic/how-common-are-rejections-after-r-r?replies=40) claim that all of their RR are accepted, except once or twice.
5. A comment from the same link claims that the post RR acceptance rate is 75% but for top 5 is about 50%
6. A comment from the same link claims that the post RR acceptance rate is 90% but for top 5 is guessed to be 75%.
7. Two [anonymous](https://www.econjobrumors.com/topic/probability-of-acceptance-after-rr) [comments](https://www.econjobrumors.com/topic/whats-the-difference-between-rr-and-conditional-acceptance) claim that the post RR acceptance rate is 50% for tops. 80% for mid-range.
8. All of my friends and professors says that R&R lead to acceptance with high probability unless it is top-5 journals.
9. According to JoF editorial reports, the post RR acceptance rate is 58.8 in 2009, 45.9% in 2010, and 90% in 2019. This is a **very reliable data** for Finance. I am looking for similar data in one of the economics journals.

Comment: I believe this is impossible to say in general because it depends too much on individual characteristics of the editor (and the referees).

Comment: You may be able to get acceptance rates from Cabells, but it is not entirely economics - oriented and I have noticed gaps in their data.  I believe it is a paid service. https://liu.cwp.libguides.com/c.php?g=45770&p=3161505

Comment: @RegressForward Are they providing post-RR acceptance rate or only the raw acceptance rate?

Comment: @Bayesian Well, there are some official data for Journal of Finance, whose post-RR acceptance rate is about 50%, which is pretty consistent around 2010. This acceptance rate was gradually increased to 90% since 2017, though.